# How to implement ng-show as toggle in multi-level ng-repeat

Tags: html, angularjs, ng-show

```
 1. level1
    -lvl1A
     --lvl1A1
     --lvl1A2
       ---lvl1A2X
       ---lvl1A2Y

    -lvl2A
     --lvl2A1
     --lvl2A2

 2. level2
```

this is just the sample of multilevel ng-repeat ul li element.
on click of any level only next level data will show or hide not the entire data.

kindly give me some solution to this scenario.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Where is your HTML? Where is your javascript? What did you try so far? Where is the problem?

Comment: Hi Egan , this is just a sample ul li element.
Instead of giving negative feedback try to understand structure and resolve it.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a WriteACodeForMe site. It looks like you even didn't try to solve your problem. What you are asking for is quite easy, it's like basics of Angular. Of course there might be some problems and if you have some, ask a question and somebody will help you. But show your effort.

Comment: I am new to angularjs .. and i am not saying WriteACodeForMe . atleast give me some logic instead of giving me feedback.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this in some of my spare time.. it might not be the best way to do it.

```js
angular.module("myApp", []).
controller("TreeController", ['$scope',
  function($scope) {
    $scope.delete = function(data) {
      data.nodes = [];
      return false;
    };
    $scope.add = function(data) {
      var post = data.nodes.length + 1;
      var newName = data.name + '-' + post;
      var showSub = false;
      data.nodes.push({
        name: newName,
        showSub: showSub,
        nodes: []
      });
      return false;
    };
    $scope.tree = [{
      name: "Node",
      showSub: false,
      nodes: []
    }];
  }
]);
```

```html
<script type="text/ng-template" id="tree_item_renderer.html">
  {{data.name}}
  <button ng-click="add(data);  $event.stopPropagation();">Add node</button>
  <button ng-click="delete(data);  $event.stopPropagation();" ng-show="data.nodes.length > 0">Delete nodes</button>
  <ul ng-show="data.showSub">
    <li ng-repeat="data in data.nodes" ng-include="'tree_item_renderer.html'" ng-click="data.showSub = !data.showSub; $event.stopPropagation();"></li>
  </ul>
</script>

<ul ng-app="Application" ng-controller="TreeController">
  <li ng-repeat="data in tree" ng-include="'tree_item_renderer.html'" ng-click="data.showSub = !data.showSub"></li>
</ul>
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mubashirhanif/6baa8dbd/3/)

Comment: Hi Minato thanks, but can you try by using ng-show and ng-hide.

Comment: I have used `ng-show="data.showSub"` in the template if you could see it.. its just a prototype and you can use and understand it to fit your needs.

Comment: it's because.. your question is too broad.. your question should be very precise and should be a specific problem which can be answered precisely.. like you are facing some error and stuff.. implementing a feature can have many possible ways to be solved... be specific..

Comment: Thank you  mubashir Bhai :-)

Comment: No Problem.. @Anil Glad I could help :)